# Django Forms - is it advisable to change user submitted data in the clean method

Tags: django-forms

I have the following code in my Django project:

```
def my_view(request):
   form = MyForm(request.POST):
   if form.is_valid():
       instance = form.save(commit = False)
       instance.some_field = 'foo'
       form.save()
   #...
```

The question is, is it advisable to rewrite this the following way:

forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):   
       # ...

   def clean(self):
       form.some_field = 'foo'
```

I wonder, if `clean` method should be used exclusively for data validation, or I could also perform here some business logic stuff, thus making my views more concise and devoid of business logic details.

One of possible advantages of making the assignment in the `clean` method is that sometimes data validation could be dependent on `some_field`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered putting it in .save?